# Is the set of almost perfect numbers closed under multiplication?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**Question**

> **Is the set of almost perfect numbers closed under multiplication?**

It is known that $2^k$ for integral $k \geq 0$ are [almost perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number).  It is also known (by work of Antalan and Tagle) that if $M \neq 2^k$ is an *even almost perfect number*, then $M = 2^r b^2$ where $b$ is an odd composite.  Finally, it is known (by work of [Antalan and Dris](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04248)) that $b^2$ is *not* almost perfect.

Hence, it seems easy to show the following *Proposition*.

> **Proposition**  The set **APN** of almost perfect numbers is closed under multiplication if and only if **APN** $= \left\{2^k | k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}\right\}$.

Comment: Having shown your proposition, the answer to your question is that we don't know if the set of almost perfect numbers is closed under multiplication.  Otherwise you would have shown that there are no almost perfect numbers other than $2^k$.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I agree.  The point of my question was actually to reformulate the problem in terms of set theory (and perhaps, abstract algebra).

Comment: That is a reasonable approach.  When we don't know if a proposition is true, one can find as many equivalents as possible and see if we can prove any one of them.  The parallel postulate and the axiom of choice come to mind.  I don't see what your question is here as I wouldn't expect anybody to be able to answer the question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to be posted in the *Comments* section and is not really an answer - I just wanted to collect some of my recent thoughts on this problem here.

The definition of a set $S$ being closed under some binary operation $*$ is the following:
$$\forall a, b \in S, a * b \in S.$$

The negation of this statement is:
$$\exists a, b \in S, a * b \not\in S.$$

So now suppose that the set of almost perfect numbers **APN** is *not closed* under multiplication.

Then there exists $x, y \in$ **APN**, such that $xy \not\in$ **APN**.

But $x, y \in$ **APN** means that
$$\sigma(x) = 2x - 1$$
and
$$\sigma(y) = 2y - 1$$
where $\sigma = \sigma_{1}$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.

This implies that
$$2xy - D(xy) = \sigma(xy) \leq \sigma(x)\sigma(y) = (2x - 1)(2y - 1) = 4xy - 2x - 2y + 1$$
from which it follows that
$$D(xy) \geq -2xy-2x-2y+1 = 3-2(x+1)(y+1),$$
where $D(n)=2n-\sigma(n)$ is the [deficiency](https://oeis.org/A033879) of $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $D(xy) \neq 1$ (since $xy \not\in$ **APN**).

Alas, we do not arrive at a contradiction.